# In app credit/currency using PayPal API

Tags: cakephp, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, credits

I am building a web app in cakePHP that involves a credit system.
So credits are bought with real money, then at a some point in the future they are spent and the portion the credits value goes to me and the rest goes to a third party.

So far no problem but...

If I use something like PayPal's Express Checkout, PayPal take a cut when the credits are initially bought and another cut when the third party is paid.

Or I can use PayPal's Adaptive Payments and do a Delayed Chained Payment but that has a maximum delay of 90 days.

So my question is do I have any other options?

Answer (score 0):

There are only two options:

- Use another payment service provider, but they'll all take their share for their service. But Paypal has become expensive.
- Add the fees on top of what the user has to pay for the credits, you'll have to calculate them in advance.